# C# - ReportViewer no agrega BindingSource

Tags: c#, reportviewer

tengo un problema con visual studio, agrego un report viewer y elijo mi rdlc creado, pero no me crea los bindingsource automáticamente, aunque los cree desde el cuadro de herramientas y asigne los conjuntos de datos, no me muestra nada en el reporte.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando cargo el reporte me muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y si tengo asignados mis origenes de datos em mi rdlc.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo puede resolver así

```
    private void getSalesReport(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        SalesReport reportModel = new SalesReport();
        reportModel.createSalesOrderReport(startDate, endDate);
        // Convierto en binding
        var binding = new BindingSource();
        binding.DataSource = reportModel;
        //
        this.reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Desarrollo\Grilla\Grilla\Reportes\SalesReport.rdlc";
        //
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SalesReport", binding));
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("salesListing", reportModel.salesListing));
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("netSalesByPeriod", reportModel.netSalesByPeriod));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo resuelve esto el problema del OP (autor de la pregunta)?