# No aparecen los BindingSource al seleccionar reporte desde el visor de reportes 2022

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con visual studio community 2022, creo un reprote con ReporteViewer (SSRS), luego desde un formulario agrego el visor de reportes y no me aparecen los BindingSource en la parte inferior como lo hacia en versiones anteriores, lo que si logro ver es que crea una carpeta llamada DataSources y ahi me muestra algo, necesito hacer esto:

```
SalesReport reportModel = new SalesReport();
reportModel.createSalesOrderReport(startDate, endDate);
SalesReportBindingSource.DataSource = reportModel;
SalesListingBindingSource.DataSource = reportModel.salesListing;
NetSalesByPeriodBindingSource.DataSource = reportModel.netSalesByPeriod;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Y necesito lo que no me aparece que son los BindingSource:
SalesReportBindingSource
SalesListingBindingSource
NetSalesByPeriodBindingSource

No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos "CNReporte"

Ya alguien pregunto antes pero no hubo respuesta:
[C# - ReportViewer no agrega BindingSource](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507090/c-reportviewer-no-agrega-bindingsource)

Como podría hacer por favor...

Gracias...

Comment: En otra respuesta de SO (inglés) comentan que puedes editar el archivo con extensión RDLC. Primero cambiar `CNReporte` por el nombre del BindingSource (supongo que será el valor de `reportModel.Name`) y por último editar los nombres de los "fields" del archivo RDLC para que sean iguales a los nombres de las columnas de tu BindingSource. Fuente: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453146/unable-to-bind-datasource-to-reportviewer` Lo que está claro es que el archivo RDLC debe tener los campos correctos y los nombres correctos.

Comment: Realice el camnio que me dijiste para nada aun sigue con el error...

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver así:

```
    private void getSalesReport(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        SalesReport reportModel = new SalesReport();
        reportModel.createSalesOrderReport(startDate, endDate);
        // Convierto en binding
        var binding = new BindingSource();
        binding.DataSource = reportModel;
        //
        this.reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"C:\Desarrollo\Grilla\Grilla\Reportes\SalesReport.rdlc";
        //
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("SalesReport", binding));
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("salesListing", reportModel.salesListing));
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("netSalesByPeriod", reportModel.netSalesByPeriod));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).